# Ionic - keyboard doesn't open when calling textElement.focus() on iOS 13

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic-webview

Calling element.focus() on text element doesn't open keyboard on iOS 13. This is working fine on iOS versions < 13. I'm using cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Any idea?

Comment: use `(ionFocus)="youFunction"`.